# AppleScript choose file with Terminal action

Tags: terminal, applescript

I would to choose a file/an image that is being mounted in the Terminal

```
set pathelection to POSIX path of (choose file of type {"sparsebundle", "sparseimage", "dmg"})
```

do shell script "hdiutil mount" & " " & pathelection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Is this part of a larger script?  The reason I'm asking is you can just simply double-click an image file in Finder and it's going to mount automatically, so no need to script it by itself.

Comment: I'd assume so. Based on the syntax he used, it's also possible he's just in the process of learning, since some of it is peculiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have no clue what you want, but your code isn't guaranteed to work, which may be your problem. Try this:

```
set image to POSIX path of (choose file of type {"sparsebundle", "sparseimage", "dmg", "cdr", "iso"})
do shell script "hdiutil mount " & quoted form of image
```

Source: Part-time work as a prophet

Comment: Make that a prophet of satan. This post got my rep to 666.

Comment: lol I had that once :) let's change it since another kind soul did it for me, just for that.